# "more than one remote source not supported" while using pscp

Tags: windows-10, ssh, putty, scp, pscp

*I have Windows 10 pro and I'm using the latest version of pscp/putty through command prompt.*

I I am trying to do a file transfer from my Windows 10 computer to an SSH server, but I'm running into the issue of "more than one remote source not supported"

I'm inputting

```
pscp.exe C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\ssh\test.txt username@ip.ip.ip -P 2022 -i C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\ssh\priv.ppk -pw Password : /minecraft/plugins
```

And getting out

```
More than one remote source not supported
```

Obviously replace "username" for my username, "ip" for the parts of the ip, and "Password" for my password.

Anyone know how to fix/what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [`pscp` syntax for upload](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage) is:

```
pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
pscp.exe -P 2022 -i C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\ssh\priv.ppk -pw Password C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\ssh\test.txt username@ip.ip.ip:/minecraft/plugins
```

---

Also, are you sure you need both a key and a password?

Comment: I tried that syntax with this input:   **pscp.exe -P 2022 -i C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\ssh\priv.ppk -pw R!dger4756 C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\ssh\text.txt minecraft@brad.eats.asia : /minecraft/plugins** and got the same output. any clue why? and yes, the owner of the ssh server requires both a passphrase and private key.

Comment: You still have spaces around `:`. + Server owner cannot require a *passphrase*. The *passphrase* is a local method for protecting your private key. It has no effect server-side. + The *password* and the *passphrase* are two different things. `-pw` is for the ***p**ass**w**ord*.